# Preg Replace Help for php string

Tags: preg-replace

```
$testString = 'this is testing start [youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd&w=640&h=390] this is last';
```

I want this to be replace by following :

```
$testString = 'this is testing start <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd&w=640&h=390"></iframe> this is last';
```

Kindly Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

try this:

```
$testString = 'this is testing start [youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd&w=640&h=390] this is last'; 

$new_String = strtr($testString, array('[' => '<iframe src="', ']' => '"></iframe>'));
```